# Query giving error ora-00923 from keyword not found where expected

Tags: sql, row-number, oracle8i

I am using Oracle 8i. When I tried to run this below script I am getting the error ora-00923 from keyword not found where expected.

Please find the below query which I am using.

```sql
select i.siid, 
       sp.access_point_status, 
       csp.id_number, 
       act.entry_time, 
       act.addnl_info, 
       row_num() over (partition by i.siid order by act.entry_time desc)  act_row 
from  table_Service_point sp,
      table_case_to_service_point csp,
      table_case cs, 
      table_act_entry act, 
      (select distinct siid, 
              iopt.installedopts2axspoint
       from table_installed_options iopt, 
            tmp_efms_clarify inp 
       where iopt.siid = inp.service_instance 
         and iopt.siid = 'DSL580155-105-1') i 
where sp.objid = csp.case2servicepoint 
  and csp.id_number = cs.id_number 
  and cs.objid = act.act_entry2case 
  and sp.objid = i.installedopts2axspoint
```

Comment: Which _exact_ version of that ancient 8i release? Window functions (aka "analytical functions") were added in 8.1 - they were not available in 8.0 (and why are you still using a version that has bee de-supported for over a decade?)

Answer (score 1):

Try using row_number() instead of row_num().

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes `''` in `oracle` denote `characters`, not `names`.

Replace

```
iopt.siid='DSL580155-105-1'
```

with

```
iopt.siid="DSL580155-105-1"
```

Comment: How do you know that there is a column named `"DSL580155-105-1"`? Plus: this is nothing special to Oracle. The SQL standard defines character literals to be enclosed in single quotes and identifiers in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I do think `row_number()` is the correct spelling, not `row_num()`. Google it for more on how it works. And also, just a reminder, is `DSL580155-105-1` actually a column?